# Ajax call fails to receive a list of objects from controller action method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateCountryDropDownList(string ContinentId)
{
        HotelContext H = new HotelContext();
        int ContinentID = int.Parse(ContinentId);
        List<Country> Co = H.Country.Where(x => x.ContinentId == ContinentID).ToList();
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "element1", "element2", "element3" });

        return Json(new { ListResult = Co }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I pass `mylist` instead of *Co* it work

And here is my ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Name").change(function () {
              var ContinentoId = $(this).val();

              $.ajax({
                  type: "Post",
                  dataType: "json",

                  data: { ContinentId: ContinentoId },
                  url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCountryDropDownList","Home")',

                  success: function (result) {
                      alert("worked");
                  },
                  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                      alert("failed");
                  }
```

It give my failed message when passing list of country object but success when passing list of strings. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is inspect WHY your call failed.

Instead of doing `alert('failed')` do something like `console.log(arguments)` and look at your browsers dev tools (console) to find the actual message.

I would hazard a guess that your error message would be along the lines of no method exists.

Your controller is only setup to receive a single string.

`public JsonResult UpdateCountryDropDownList(string ContinentId)`

If you want to be able to `POST` a list of string, then change your controller to accept a `List<string>`, such as (note i changed the name of the parameter)

`public JsonResult UpdateCountryDropDownList(List<string> ContinentIds)`

You will then be able to post an array of strings - adjust your ajax call to something like:

`data: { ContinentIds: ["1","2","3"]}`

None of this is tested, though the concept is there.

Comment: I want to pass only one string which is dropdown list's selected value
to use this value to populate another dropdownlist with data.

I used console.log(arguments)

i got this error 

http://s31.postimg.org/rzl4kecmz/2016_04_20_140543.png

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means your controller method is throwing and exception. Inspect the response in the Network tab to get the details of the error. And is `ContinentId` is an `int`, then make you parameter `int` (not `string`)

Comment: The value returned from dropdownlist is of string type, i pass it to function and convert it to int later, also i found that i cant return json result containing objects, i must convert to jsonstring using JsonConvert.SerializeObject or smth like that, iam trying to figure out how to solve it

Comment: @MazenKamal, If the value your sending can be converted to an `int` then the parameter should be `int ContinentId`! (the value returned from the dropdownlist is not typeof `string` - its just text - your browser has no concept of c# types). You need to learn to debug your code.